Powershell changes formatting when redirecting error stream
Using Node.js to demonstrate:
> node --eval "console.log('This is stdout'); console.error('This is stderr')"
This is stdout
This is stderr

But when I combine the streams by redirecting stderr to stdout (2>&1):
> node --eval "console.log('This is stdout'); console.error('This is stderr')" 2>&1
This is stdout
node : This is stderr
At line:1 char:1
+ node --eval "console.log('This is stdout'); console.error('This is st ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (This is stderr:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

From what I can tell, it seems to be taking the string from the error stream and wrapping it up in an object, causing all this extra formatting to be applied when it gets converted back to text. The same thing happens when redirecting to a file.
Is there an easy/elegant way to avoid the extra formatting being applied, having it behave like the original snippet?

Try piping to | % ToString. The object you mention is called ErrorRecord.
